# How to pass value from javascript to label in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I need to pass a javascript value to label in asp.net. The javascript function was inside JScript1.js. I pass the value to a hidden field. I already added the script to the source of the content page as below, but doesn't work whenever I called the function value to the vb.net code behind.

```
<script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's the javascript function inside a JScript1.js

```
function dateTimeToday()
{

  var month=new Array();
  month[0]="1";
  month[1]="2";
  month[2]="3";
  month[3]="4";
  month[4]="5";
  month[5]="6";
  month[6]="7";
  month[7]="8";
  month[8]="9";
  month[9]="10";
  month[10]="11";
  month[11]="12";

  var d = new Date();
  var mt=month[d.getMonth()];
  var h=d.getHours();
  var m=d.getMinutes();
  var s=d.getSeconds();

  mt=checkMonth(mt);
  m=checkTime(m);
  s=checkTime(s);

  var x = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");

  x.innerHTML=d.getFullYear()+"-"+mt+"-"+d.getDate()+" " +h+":"+m+":"+s;;

  t=setTimeout(function(){myFunction()},500);

 }

function checkTime(i)
{
  if (i<10)
   {
    i="0" + i;
   }
 return i;
}

function checkMonth(j)
 {
  if (j<10)
   {
   j="0" + j;
   }
   return j;
 }
```

Below is my code of calling the javascript value.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        lbl.Text = HiddenField1.Value
    End If  

End Sub
```

Am I missing something on my code?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of the input field, not the innerHtml:

```
var x = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");
x.value =d.getFullYear()+"-"+mt+"-"+d.getDate()+" " +h+":"+m+":"+s;
```

And consider that the ID of asp.net control can change when the page is rendered, you could use:

```
var x = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientId %>');
x.value =d.getFullYear()+"-"+mt+"-"+d.getDate()+" " +h+":"+m+":"+s;
```

Comment: It does not make a postback if that is what you mean? You still need to make a postback after this if you want to run the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to set value in Hiddenfield in javascript..You can do..

```
document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value=d.getFullYear()+"-"+mt+"-"+d.getDate()+" " +h+":"+m+":"+s;
```

In code behind..

```
lbl.Text = HiddenField1.Value;
```

Hidden input markup..

```
<input id="HiddenField1" type="hidden"  runat="server" clientidmode="Static" value=""/>
```

Comment: this one....<input id="HiddenField1" type="hidden" runat="server" clientIDMode="Static" value=""/>

Comment: set clientidmode="static"..not clientIDMode,pls.

Comment: Did you get any value inside the variable x in javascript function?

Comment: Then I hope problems with the functions you are calling?I hope a "semi colon" is extra in the particular line of code?

Comment: I don't know what's the problem on this sir..I've tried everything but no effect..I did that already, putting semi colon when calling function..

Comment: Did u remove extra semi-colon in this line..x.innerHTML=d.getFullYear()+"-"+mt+"-"+d.getDate()+" " +h+":"+m+":"+s;;..

Comment: Did you try putting an alert(x); to check the value of x?If yes what you are getting?

Comment: What you are getting as alert?

Comment: the value of x which is the current date and time sir

Comment: Is that the value you should get in the Hiddenfield?

Comment: Then whats the next problem?

Comment: i can't bind it on label in asp sir

Comment: i tried putting the code on a page without master page..i put it on body on load=dateTimeToday() and it works..but in content page with master page it didn't work because there's no body

Comment: So where are u now calling dateTimeToday()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51577/discussion-between-jameem-and-j-j)